# How to convert form UTF-8 to Latin/Arabic and vice versa?

Tags: c++, utf-8, ansi

Is there a cross-platform way to convert from UTF-8 to Latin/Arabic and from Latin/Arabicto UTF-8 in C++?

Comment: ANSI/Windows-1252 is not able to represent all the characters UTF-8 can. So no, you can't reliably convert, unless you define some escape mechanism extending 1252.

Comment: @Erik: Even worse, "ANSI" in this context is a weasel word for "whatever encoding is set at this moment" - it's not even guaranteed to be Windows-1252.

Comment: I care about a specific set of characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-6)

Comment: @Abdelwahed: Hmm, it should be possible to convert this to UTF8, just make a table mapping the (single-byte) characters of IES_8859-6 to (variable-length) UTF8 characters. The opposite way is harder - you'll need to replace every character that's not in the mapping into some placeholder, e.g. `?`.

Comment: @Piskvor: There's really no need to code those table-lookups yourself. Although, of course, it would not be too hard. The inverse may be harder, even once you have UTF-8 split into logical characters: I haven't checked if 8859-6 has any characters which have more than one representation in Unicode, where you may have combining characters such as a+¨ for an ä (which also exists).

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig: You are correct, of course: no need to re-invent the wheel. Also, the existing libraries might normalize the character representations for you, as you noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are libraries like [icu](http://icu-project.org/) available. But Erik is, of course, right: The round-trip from Unicode through ISO 8859-6 will be lossy. (Yes, UTF-8 is “Unicode.” UTF-16, is “Unicode,” too, just having different bit-patterns for the same code number. See [Joel Spolsky's text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) if you didn't know that. Or if you haven't read it yet, it's good material.)

Comment: icu contains examples, e.g., in http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icuapps/trunk/translitdemo/

Answer (score 0):

There is not, but there is a cross-platform way to convert between unicode represented in `wchar_t` (which is 16-bit on Windows and 32-bit on most of the other platforms) and whatever is set as locale character encoding in the system using `wcstombs`/`mbstowcs` routines from standard C library or `codecvt` facet of `locale` in standard C++ library. The conversion between `wchar_t`, where each element is one codepoint and utf-8 is than quite simple. So you can write or copy from somewhere a routine to convert between utf-8 and unicode in `wchar_t` and combine it with `wcstombs`/`mbstowcs`.